# How to skip a portion of a line in Java- Don't know what I am doing

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to only use every other number in a string of numbers.
This is how the xml file content comes to us, but I only want to use The first group and then every other group.
The second number in each group can be ignored. The most important number are the first like 1,3,5 and 29
Can you help? Each group equals “x”:”x”,

```
<CatcList>{“1":"15","2":"15","3":"25","4":"25","5":"35","6":"35","29":"10","30":"10"}</CatcList>
```

Right now my script looks like this, but I am not the one who wrote it.

I only included the portion that would be needed. The StartPage would be the variable used.
If you have knowledge of how to add 1 to the EndPage Integer, that would be very helpful as well.
Thank you!

```
 Util.StringList xs;
 line.parseLine(",", "", xs);
 for (Int i=0; i<xs.Size; i++) {
   Int qty = xs[i].right(xs[i].Length - xs[i].find(":")-1).toInt()-1;
   for (Int j=0; j<qty; j++) {
      Output_0.File.DocId = product;
      Output_0.File.ImagePath = Image;
      Output_0.File.ImagePath1 = Image;
  Output_0.File.StartPage = xs[i].left(xs[i].find(("-"))).toInt()-1;
  Output_0.File.EndPage = xs[i].mid(xs[i].find("-")+1, (xs[i].find(":") - xs[i].find("-")-1)).toInt()-0;
      Output_0.File.Quantity = qty.toString();
      Output_0.File.commit();
```

Comment: I should clarify, it is not the CATCList field I needed, just showing that for what content comes down in the XML. I need to Output_0.File.StartPage code altered to do what I said in the first paragraph. For example, I want to only use the 1 in the first group “1":"15" and the 3 in the next group of "3":"25"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
,?("(?<num>\d+)":"\d+"),?("\d+":"\d+")?
```

The group called num will contain every other occurrence of the first part of "x":"x"

so for the values:

```
"1":"14","2":"14","3":"14","4":"24","5":"33","6":"44","7":"55"
```

the group called 'num' will contain 1 3 5 and 7.

[see example here](https://regex101.com/r/O2LSIN/2)

Edit: Once you have the numbers extracted, you can do with it what you need:

```
Pattern datePatt = Pattern.compile(",?(\"(?<num>\\d+)\":\"\\d+\"),?(\"\\d+\":\"\\d+\")?");
String dateStr = "\"1\":\"14\",\"2\":\"14\",\"3\":\"14\",\"4\":\"24\",\"5\":\"33\",\"6\":\"44\",\"7\":\"55\"";
Matcher m = datePatt.matcher(dateStr);

while (m.find()) {          
    System.out.printf("%s%n", m.group("num"));           
}
```

Comment: That seems like what I need, but where do I put this in relation to the above code? Bear with me, I know nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pattern with a loop and some condition to extract this information :

```
String string = "<CatcList>{\"1\":\"15\",\"2\":\"15\",\"3\":\"25\",\"4\":\"25\","
        + "\"5\":\"35\",\"6\":\"35\",\"29\":\"10\",\"30\":\"10\"}</CatcList> ";
String regex = "\"(\\d+)\":\"\\d+\"";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
int index = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (index % 2 == 0) {//From your question you have to get alternative results 1 3 5 ...
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " ---> " + matcher.group());
    }
    index++;
}
```

**Outputs**

```
1 ---> "1":"15"
3 ---> "3":"25"
5 ---> "5":"35"
29 ---> "29":"10"
```

---

The regex `"(\d+)":"\d+"` should match any combination of a `"number":"number"` i used `(\d+)` so I can get only the information of this group.

Answer (score 0):

That XML value looks like a JSON map. All that .right, .mid, and .left code looks pretty confusing to me without details of how those methods work.  Does something like this seem more clear:

```
// leaving out all the backslash escapes of the embedded quotes
String xmlElement = "{"1":"15","2":"15","3":"25","4":"25","5":"35","6":"35","29":"10","30":"10"}";
xmlElement = xmlElement.replaceAll("[}{]", "");
String[] mapEntryStrings = xmlElement.split(","); 
Map<Integer, String> oddStartPages = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (String entry : mapEntryStrings) {
    String[] keyAndValue = entry.split(":");
    int key = Integer.parseInt(keyAndValue[0]);
    if (key % 2 == 1) {// if odd 
        oddStartPages.put(key, keyAndValue[1]);
    }
}
```

Then, the set of keys in the oddStartPages Map is exactly the set of first numbers in your "first and every other group" requirement.